# Extract argument code of a function in R/Subset function based on argument names

Tags: r, function, r-caret, args, rfe

I am working with `caret` package. There are many functions which uses `methods` inside it. Example,

```
  rfe
  methods(rfe)
  rfe.default
```

To check arguments of `rfe.default` we use `args()` function, or `formalArgs()` or `formals()`

```
  args(rfe.default)
  formalArgs(rfe.default)
  formals(rfe.default)
```

Now, I just want to see the codes for each argument used inside `rfe.default` function, instead of whole function code which we get by typing

```
  rfe.default
```

How to get the codes just for those arguments.

We can use `deparse()` function to get the range of lines from the function code. But is there any way to get the codes of arguments from the function based on argument names.

If an argument is using a function within it like here `rfeContol = rfeControl()`

I should be able to extract just this argument's code from `rfe.default` function instead of the whole code or `rfe.default`.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean like `grep("rfeControl", deparse(rfe.default), value = TRUE)`?

Comment: @RichScriven I dont think so because it would be like getting only those lines which have that word in it. if you type `formalArgs(rfe.default)`, the list of arguments it gives, I want to extract each one of them separately as in the code and not the value of those arguments, but the function that is there behind when user provides value to that argument.

Comment: @RichScriven The grep would to just like searching for words and not like proper part of code. It would give us lines having that word because you have used `deparse()`.

Comment: @RichScriven  have solved my problem, just found out by creating my own small function and doing some function based commands. Also your `grep` with `deparse()` would help for some part. 
Thanks.

Comment: Its little bit complicated to explain here.